# Generic REST Service To Store Attachments - what type of parameters to require

Tags: java, rest

I am working on a REST service for handling file attachments.  The service will be referenced by several of our internal services that have a need to store file attachments.

I have decided to store metadata in the database but I am having some issues with best way to name the files.  I cannot take the name provided as the only thing because the same name could, theoretically, be provided by 2 different internal services.  I thought about adding date/time to the filename but the calling service needs to know how to ask for what they need so if I change the name that gets lost.  I was thinking of requiring some kind of key (ticket number, event number, etc.) but that means I also need to know the name of the calling service.

So, from a generic attachment service view - what would be the typical data to be passed that would make it possible to store, and return, file attachment information?

I appreciate this could be a subject discussion but in my googling I have not found much helpful information so I am willing to listen to suggestions and put my design together taking this advise in consideration.  While I will be writing in Java this question is product agnostic.

Comment: you could always send the filename you've chosen as part of the response header (or even the payload, if you have one already). The client needs to remember it

Comment: Will each attachment be sent from a client who is logged in with a username and a given session?

Comment: Hashing the attachment would give you something unique to reference, along with providing a set of filters to store along with the hash value for reference.  Depends on the relationship between the attachments and the other internal services.

Answer (score 0):

- Ideally, I would do it this way and it worked for our application for
  a very long time. It may not be the best solution.   The caller sends
  the filename and file content.
- The callee saves the file, file name and unique id for the file.
- If it is from different caller systems then a caller identification
  code(unique for a caller).
- When the caller asks you list of files, you can send the name, id.
  Caller can display the filename in the UI and keep the id as hidden.
- When the caller requires a particular file, (s)he should send the id
  and you can get the file contents from id from your content
  management/NAS/DB.

Answer (score 0):

Use generated random UUID as a file name and return it in the "Location" header of response, e.g.

```
Status: 201 Created
Location: https://<hostname>/<path>/<UUID>
```